# SSRS report is running slow in report browser

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

It should be simple process but unable to find solution and need your help.

The report is executing faster when I run the report locally (SSDT - VS2012) but when I deploy the report to report server, it is taking a lot of time to display the report.

I checked the stored procedure (SQL Server 2008R2) and it is running fast without any issues.

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924144/why-does-the-2nd-t-sql-query-run-much-faster-than-the-first-when-called-by-repor/16929881#16929881) regarding [parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/) to see if that is the cause.

Comment: Is just the first call slow? If so, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207049/sql-reporting-services-first-call-is-very-slow) and [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2735/prevent-sql-server-reporting-services-slow-startup/).

Answer (score 0):

As this should be a simple process I noticed that the issue is with one of the table in Stored Procedure. The retrieval of records from that table is taking a lot of time. If the data retrieval from the view itself is slow then I believe we can add Indexes there. It will definitely help.

In addition while testing the report, I found that after the first execution, the stored procedure was returning records faster. However, I removed the background image for slide 3 and the third slide is loading faster (1-2 sec Max) than before in test when compared to Production (10-11 sec).

Thanks all off you for your time and efforts. :)